# Java get webpage source or timeout

Tags: java, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch data from a webpage, but if the page isn't available the program runs for a long time until it timeouts. I need it to try to get the webpage for 10 seconds and if it doesn't get a response in that time it returns null. How can I make it to work that way, please?

Here is how I get the data:

```
public int getThreadData( String address ) throws IOException{
    String valueString = null;
    URL url = new URL( "http://" + address + ":8080/web-console/ServerInfo.jsp" );
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) 
         Gecko/20100401" );
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader
        ( urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ) );

    String inputLine;

    while ( ( inputLine = br.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        if ( inputLine.contains( "#Threads" ) )
        {
            valueString = inputLine.substring( inputLine.indexOf( "/b>" ) + 3 );
            valueString = valueString.substring( 0, valueString.indexOf( "<" ) );
        }
    }
    br.close();

    return Integer.parseInt( valueString );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the connection timeout like following:

```
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000); // 10000 milliseconds
```

Comment: No, I haven't :D Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a HTTP library (like [Apache's HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)) that can simplify these things vastly. If you were using HTTPClient, you would do something like this:

```
            // Set the timeout to 20-seconds.
            final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 20 * 1000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 20 * 1000);

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, httpParams);
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
            HttpResponse response;
            response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

Comment: `HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout` is vastly more simple than `UrlConnection.setConnectTimeout`?